# vb.net opening custom file extension with clickonce application

Tags: vb.net

My program has two different major functions.
By Default - opening the program itself with the .appref-ms (desktop shortcut) opens the program in the normal mode.

I have also created a .TRA extension. When a .TRA file is opened with my program it should open the program in a secondary mode.
I can see that my program has been registered with the .tra extension and the icons have all been changed.
If I drag a file with the .TRA extension onto the .exe file in the debugging bin it opens as-expected in this second mode. However, by simply double-clicking the .TRA file it is still opening in the default mode.

The code is set to look at all of the command lines passed for the .TRA extension:

```
For i = 0 To System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs.Length
            Dim _file = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(i)
            Dim format As String = IO.Path.GetExtension(_file)
            If format = ".TRA" Then
                file = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(i)
                openedwithext = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
```

What am I missing?
Is double-clicking my .TRA file not sending a command-line argument to my app as I'm thinking it does?
How else could this be performed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is firing up the correct app though. But it is not passing the .TRA file as an argument when it opens. It is just opening the .TRA file like it would if I were to open the file from the .appref-ms

Comment: AAaack - I was thinking about shell extension - things that pop up menus in Explorer when over a specific file type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the .appref-ms works like a shortcut it takes the commandline arguments differently.
I solved the issued by adding the System.Deployment namespace and using the following code on the .loaded event.

```
        'Are we launching as a click-once?
        If (IsNetworkDeployed) Then
            Try
                Dim urifile As New Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData(0))
                Dim uristring As String = urifile.ToString
                If uristring.Contains(".TRA") Then
                    file = uristring.Substring(8) 'Substring removes the - file:///
                    openedwithext = True
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End If
```